# Django 1.4 and NoReverseMatch at /admin/ error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am getting this error when trying to access my admin panel after updating to Django 1.4 - the error is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/
Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My best guess is that I'm defining a logout urlpattern which is somehow conflicting with the one the admin panel is trying to create?  Although, it should be creating /admin/logout, right?  I did update my ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX to STATIC_URL and moved them to a sub-folder called admin, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

In my urls.py, I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    ('^logout/$',  RedirectView.as_view(url='/login/index.html')),
    (r'^login/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/fullpath/to/media/login'}),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/fullpath/to/media/static'}),
    (r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And in my settings.py, I have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/fullpath/to/myapp/media/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
     ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Should be

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

(.*) would eat up all anything following admin as the view argument.

Also, do you know what is calling `reverse('logout')`? In my local 1.4 install, the admin is namespaced and I have to call `reverse('admin:logout')`

Comment: Thanks, the (.*) was the problem.  I may have been reading the error wrong - after it worked, I tried adding the (.*) back in, and got another error with the reverse lookup error, and it didn't show the admin: prefix the traceback showed it occurring when a reverse('admin:xxx)

Comment: I had a very similar issue, but I had `r'^admin/$',`. Changing it back to `r'^admin/,` fixed the issue.